# Querying and Filtering related models in DRF

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have `Contact` model to list the followers of an `User` object, I try to filter the contacts of a `User` but I still could not manage get a correct `queryset`. My `Contact` model is simple with two `ForeignKey`:

```
class Contact(models.Model):
    user_from = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='rel_from_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)       
    user_to = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='rel_to_set', on_delete=models.CASCADE,)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} follow {}'.format(self.user_from, self.user_to)
```

I have created serializers for `User` and `Contact`:

```
##Contact Serializer
class ContactsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user_from = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    user_to = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Contact
        fields = ["user_from", "user_to"]
##UserSerializer
class UserInformationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    followers = ContactsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'followers']
```

​
And try to make a query through views:

```
class FollowerListView(APIView):
    queryset = Contact.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ContactsSerializer
    lookup_field = "username"
    
    def get(self, request, format=None, slug=None):
        kwarg_username = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        user = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).filter(username=kwarg_username)
        print(user.username)
        contacts = Contact.objects.filter(user_to=user.id)
        serializer = ContactsSerializer(contacts)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Now I get error message:

```
AttributeError at /api/member/ytsejam/followers/
'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'username'
        print(user.username)
```

If i try `print(user)` I can see the user an `Object`.
Can you guide me how to correct?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`filter` will always return a queryset. If you expect to retrieve one single item, use `get`.

So that it looks like that:

```py
def get(self, request, format=None, slug=None):
        kwarg_username = self.kwargs.get("slug")
        user = User.objects.filter(is_active=1).get(username=kwarg_username)
        print(user.username)
        contacts = Contact.objects.filter(user_to=user.id)
        serializer = ContactsSerializer(contacts)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

You could, of course, do this on one take:

```py
User.objects.get(is_active=1, username=kwarg_username)
```

But beware, if there are two rows in your model that would satisfy this call, Django will throw an error. Best make sure that the `username` has a `unique` constraint.

Comment: I solved first part of the question but I cannot view the followers under user serializer. Is not followers = ContactsSerializer(many=True, read_only=True) enough?

Comment: Your view should probably use the `UserInformationSerializer` instead of the `Contacts Serializer`?

Comment: perfect i have changed to UserInformationSerializer. check my edited code. now i need to calculate follower count.